# ¿Cómo crear un JSON a partir de una array?

Tags: javascript, json

buen día. Tengo el siguiente array:

```
[ 0.4,
     0.1,
     0.2
]
```

Almacenado en una variable `a`. Y tengo otro array con esta estructura:

```
  [ "Comida",
    "cajas,
         "desayuno"
    ]
```

Almacenado en una variable `b`.

¿Cómo puedo crear un JSON con Javascript a partir de estas dos variables para tenerlo de la siguiente forma?

```
{
"Comida":0.4,
"cajas":0.1,
"desayuno":0.2
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que esto sea lo que necesitas.

```js
function extend(obj, src) {
    dic = {};
    obj.forEach(function(element, index) {
      dic[element] = src[index];
    });
    return dic;
}

a =[ "Comida",
    "cajas",
         "desayuno"
    ];
b = [ 0.4,
     0.1,
     0.2
];


    
var c = extend(a, b);

console.log(c);

console.log(JSON.stringify(c));
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!! Justo era lo que buscaba!